# Linked list compile time error

Tags: c

In the code below I am having problems within the add_node function at compile time.

I am getting an error relating to the following line of code: `struct *node pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node))`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct list
{
   struct node *head;
   int count;
};

struct node *add_node(struct list *pList, float coef, int expo)
{
    if (pList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct *node pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (node == NULL)
    {
         return NULL;
    }

    pNode->coef = coef;
    pNode->expo = expo;
    pNode->link = pList->head;

    pList->head = pNode;
    pList->count++;

    return pNode;
}
```

Comment: never cast malloc returns

Comment: *Always* state what error you get. "An error" may as well be "disk full -- press any key to continue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this

```
struct *node pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

to

```
struct node *pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: Thanks this works but another problem has arisen in that in the following line; if ( node == NULL), the error states that node is undeclared

Comment: @user4225083 You need to do sanity check on `pNode` instead `node`.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna change the line to struct node * pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (node == NULL)
```

to

```
if (pNode == NULL)
```

Comment: I did this and it works, however a new error claims I have an undefined reference to main; collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user4225083: so the above is your *entire* program? C needs a `main` function. Guess it's time to go back to your study book.

Comment: you forgot about main function

Comment: Ok back to the books I go, thanks for the help guys.